# Structure Map Assembly version issue

Tags: masstransit

I am trying to integrate Structure map as a DI container with my mass Transit code.

It seems there is a conflict in the Nuget Packet versions .

> The assembly MassTransit.StructureMapIntegration expects a signed 
>   version 3.1.6.191  of structuremap. But the corrosponding unsigned
>   package for structure map has the latest version of 3.1.6.186.

This results in mismatch between the code.

I tried to downgrade the signed structure map assembly to 3.1.6.186 to make sure it is the same as the unsigned version of structure map, but this seems to create issues with the MassTransit Structure map Nuget package. The Mass Transit Structure Map Nuget package does not have any versions which accepts 3.1.6.186 signed structur map assembly version .

How do I get around this conflict ?

Is there another location which I can use to get MassTransit Structure Map nuget package which supports 3.1.6.186 ?

Comment: The next release of MassTransit will include support for both the signed and the unsigned version of structuremap. This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Chris ( one of the maintainers of Mass Transit ) in the comment , Mass Transit 3.2.0 now has support for unsigned Structuremap assemble which resolves this issue.